# what is the point of having static propTypes in reactjs and does it solve any problem or is it just a pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am reading the code base of a web app and I see some static PropTypes in the code .
I couldn't understand as what problem does it solve or why need them ?

Here is the code for the same .

```
static propTypes = {
    fetchCricketFantasyPlayers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,//I see this in action 
     selectedAlpha: PropTypes.array,// this comes from reducer or say redux
     history: PropTypes.object.isRequired // this seems to be related to redirecting etc.
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)** is not proper to React and it's part of JavaScript, according to MDN:

> The static keyword defines a static method for a class. Static methods
>   aren't called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on
>   the class itself. These are often utility functions, such as functions
>   to create or clone objects.

Here are two ways of declaring propTypes, and both work the same way:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return null
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  fetchCricketFantasyPlayers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,//I see this in action 
  selectedAlpha: PropTypes.array,// this comes from reducer or say redux
  history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Using static:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  static propTypes {
    fetchCricketFantasyPlayers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,//I see this in action 
    selectedAlpha: PropTypes.array,// this comes from reducer or say redux
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    return null
  }
}
```

The main difference between **[static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)** and **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)** is that you do not need to instantiate the class to access the value.

Answer (score 2):

As they say at react.

As your app grows, you can catch a lot of bugs with typechecking. For some applications, you can use JavaScript extensions like Flow or TypeScript to typecheck your whole application. But even if you don’t use those, React has some built-in typechecking abilities. To run type-checking on the props for a component, you can assign the special propTypes property

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

**One of the other benefit** of writing propTypes within the component is, we can get a view of our props and their types. So that we could pass right props next time we use the same component at some other place in our app.